# Is there any way to save my current change without Commit or Stash in Git?

Tags: git

I have changed a lot of files and I realized my approach is not good. So, I want to try another approach. I know two solutions in this case:

1. Commit: I don't want to use this feature since I know my current code doesn't work.
2. Stash: I don't want to use this as well since I miss several files and I have to re-write them again.

What I am looking for is to save my current changes somehow (without losing my current changes) and then discard some changes I don't want while keeping the rest of the changes. In this case, if I realize my second approach doesn't work either then I only need to switch to previous state.

Is there such a feature?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good use case for a regular branch to me. Is there any reason you don't want to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think @Signey_Gijzen's answer is probably best, but you can do this with `git stash apply`, too.  That is, you'll want to do:

```
$ git stash             # as usual, stashes the changes
... now your changes are gone from the working tree ...
$ git stash apply       # unstashes, but keeps stash around
... now they're all back ...
$ git stash list        # the stash will still be there
stash@{0}: WIP on master: ...
$ git show stash@{0}    # what did that stash look like again?
```

Answer (score 6):

Checkout a new branch, add your files and commit your changes there. Then change back to the branch you're previously working on.

I would use the same method for trying your second approach.

Comment: This is good idea but the thing is when I commit changes in new branch, I have to copy/paste changes of those those files I want to be there again. So, I am looking exactly to what you are suggesting but I don't want I loose my files(changes).

Comment: @Hesam Maybe you can use `git cherry-pick` so that you don't have to manually copy-paste the changes. I will add a new answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

### Git Usage *Relies* on Commits

This is a general question (e.g. there's no specific code/tree example to work from) so you're going to get a general answer. The short version is: **No, Git can't save work outside of making a commit or adding something to the index.** Even the *stash* command is a special case of a commit, and leverages these basic processes.

However, there are certainly things you can do, both inside and outside Git. Some examples include (in no particular order):

1. Do a soft reset to a known-good commit, and then cherry-pick your in-progress changes by using `git commit --patch` to select diff hunks to add to the index.
2. Copy your working tree to another directory, revert to your last known-good commit, and copy files or hunks back into your working tree as you go. For example:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/broken_wip
   cp * /tmp/broken_wip
   git reset --hard
   cp /tmp/broken_wip/somefile .
   ```
3. Create a temporary branch to store your "dirty" commits, and then change back to the main branch. You can then bring over whatever you like from your temporary branch. For example, assuming you're currently on *master*:

   ```
   git checkout -b broken_branch
   git add .
   git commit -am 'broken WIP'
   git checkout master
   ```
4. Using RCS to store your current state, while being sure not to commit the *RCS* directory or any `*,v` files.

Even if you don't want to *publish* your history, you're generally better off committing your problem code to a temporary topic branch, fixing or importing things, and then disposing of the topic branch. However, if you really need to avoid committing things to history or the index, you should probably leverage a secondary revision control system or make use of your filesystem.

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer suggested by Sidney Gizejen, I think adding a [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) step to the end would make it work for you. Assuming you are currently on branch `current_branch` and want to save your changes to branch `temp_branch`, you can do:

```
git checkout -b temp_branch
git add <the_things_you_wanna_add>
git commit -m "..."
git checkout current_branch
git cherry-pick temp_branch -n
```

The `cherry-pick` command will apply the changes introduced by the given commits. In this case, since you're passing a branch instead, it will use the last commit on that branch. the `-n` option makes it so that the changes are applied but not committed.